# How to group product based on attribute?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, hadoop, google-cloud-datastore

I have product data from different sources.

I want to put information related to a product in one place.

For example, I want to put information related to Iphone-5 from all sources to one place.

Here is the problem , all source dont have data in same way. for example for same product they have different name, some will have color with name but some will not.

Sample data :

```
Brand     |  Product Name                                   | Source | Information
Dell      |  Dell inspriron 15R 5050(Core i5/4gb/500/GB/Dos | Rev_Src| Very good product.
Dell      |  Dell inspriron 15R 5050, color: black/Blue     | Spc_Src| Ram | 4gb DDR3, Proce : 15 etc
Dell      | Dell inspriron 15r 5050 in  black color          | Stk_SRC| Available in India
DEll      | Window 7 with Dell inspiron 15r 5050 4gb ram    |usr_src | good performance
```

Like we have data for many more product,

Out put, 
I want information like,

```
Brand| Product                 | information
Dell | Dell inspiron 15 r 5050 | {Rev_Src : very good product, Rev_Src : Ram | 4 gb..., Stk_Src : available, Usr_Src : good performance}
```

Issue : Product name is not in same format in all the sources

I am looking for solution, Will map-reduce help?

If yes then should I go for Google App Engine(map reduce lib) with datastore or Hadoop.

Note : I am working on Google App Engine based Application.

Comment: show us a sample data set and what you want the output to be would be a good start ...

Comment: Hi Joran, I have added sample data

Comment: that should help get you an answer at least ... not sure offhand what the solution is ... but someone might and when I have some more time I can look at it

Comment: With how much data are you dealing? isn't a normal database/SQL grouping enough?

Comment: I am dealing with ~ 1 millions of product(from 11 different source)
SQL grouping will not work as each source have different product name.
By different name, I mean variant in product name

Comment: Your productname is more a description than a normalized tag. You need search or semantic tools to solve your problem. Have a look at the new search API: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/

Comment: Voscausa : semantic tool will be good direction. If I am not wrong then search api will help me to provide a good platform for searching similar products but not grouping them and making a single row from multiple row. Please correct me If I am wrong